# how to return the data attribute of an option element in select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to log out the data attribute i've attached to each option in my select box but with no success, am I correct using .on('change'... or what should I be doing to achieve this?

JS

```
$('select').children().on('change', function(e){
    console.log( $(this).data('id') );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML

```
<select>
<option value="1" data-id="option1">wgwg</option>
<option value="1" data-id="option2">wgwerg</option>
<option value="1" data-id="option3">wgwg</option>
<option value="1" data-id="option4">wgr</option>
</select>​
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A change event on `option` doesn't really make sense as the `option` is not changing.  The event should be on the `select`.

```
$('select').on('change', function(e){ 
    console.log( $(this).find("option:selected").data('id') ); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can it with **Vanilla Javascript**:

```
console.log(this.querySelector(':checked').getAttribute('data-id'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/GmgCs/)**

```
$('select').on('change', function(e){
    console.log( $('option:selected', this).data('id'));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Your Live Demo is very helpful -- thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to assign the event to the children of select which is wrong..
You need to assign the event to the select directly..

Also `this`  does not have the data attribute. It is the `option that is selected` .. So change your code to this

Try this

```
 $('select').on('change', function(e){
        console.log( $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-id') );
    }).change();
```

OR

```
$('select').on('change', function(e){
            console.log( $(this).find('option:selected').data('id') );
        }).change();
```

Comment: `this` is the select and the select doesn't have a `data-id`.